# Chi-square test for multiple rows contingency table

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

I was trying to figure out if/how I can apply a chi-square test to my problem.

I know how to deal with and interpret a case where I have only 2 mutually excluding groups, like male/female, and I want to determine whether a certain disease is more common in one of the groups. The null hypotheses is that there's no difference in the distribution of the disease between males and females.
I can organize the data this way:

```
       |  disease       no_disease
-----------------------------------
male   |    25              6

female |    8               15
```

and, after using a chi-square test, I can reject the null hypothesis, since I get a chi2 (11.686) higher than the critical value (3.841) for a significance of 0.05.

However, I'm trying to figure out how to deal with a situation where I have patients with multiple symptoms, so something like:

```
           |  disease   no_disease  |  TOT
---------------------------------------------
symptom 01 |    20         20       |  40

symptom 02 |    10          5       |  15

symptom 03 |    10         15       |  25

symptom 04 |    10          5       |  15
-----------------------------------------
    TOT         50         45       |  95
```

***the symptoms are mutually exclusive***, and I'd like to figure out which ones are better indicators of the presence of the disease, but I'm not sure about how to approach the problem.

I don't think performing a chi2 test on the whole table as it is would make sense, right?
I was thinking I could treat them separately. For each symptom, I could create a single contingency table, considering the patients with the current symptom as a first category, and grouping together all the other ones not presenting the current symptom in a second category...so, something like:

```
           |  disease   no_disease  |  TOT
---------------------------------------------
symptom 01 |    20         20       |  40

no sympt01 |    30         25       |  55
-----------------------------------------
    TOT         50         45       |  95


           |  disease   no_disease  |  TOT
---------------------------------------------
symptom 02 |    10          5       |  15

no sympt02 |    40         40       |  80
-----------------------------------------
    TOT         50         45       |  95


           |  disease   no_disease  |  TOT
---------------------------------------------
symptom 03 |    10         15       |  25

no sympt03 |    40         30       |  70
-----------------------------------------
    TOT         50         45       |  95



           |  disease   no_disease  |  TOT
---------------------------------------------
symptom 04 |    10          5       |  15

no sympt04 |    40         40       |  80
-----------------------------------------
    TOT         50         45       |  95
```

and then perform chi2 tests on each table, to evaluate how much each symptom is an indicator of the presence of the disease.
But again, I don't know if it would be a correct approach.

Answer (score 2):

You may fit a loglinear model:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-linear_analysis

Answer (score 2):

Since the symptoms are mutually exclusive, a chisquare test on the complete table is meaningful, but not very informative.  I would fit a logistic regression, but a loglinear model as suggested by @Christian Hennig: Is probably equivalent.

There are many posts here about contingency tables and logistic regression, see [Logistic regression vs chi-square in a 2x2 and Ix2 (single factor - binary response) contingency tables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177816/logistic-regression-vs-chi-square-in-a-2x2-and-ix2-single-factor-binary-respo)   and   [chi square test vs logistic regression result](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/570544/chi-square-test-vs-logistic-regression-result)